# Import huge SQL file(6GB+) to MySQL on VPS

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a DB from .sql file, but it's impossible, cause like I said is over 6GB with a lot of records in it and I hit the limit of max_allowed_packet. I use my cPanel user to login in mysql via PuTTy, but it requires SUPER privileges to set this variable(max_allowed_packet).

Comment: Have you tried MySQL workbench server administration tool?

Answer (score 5):

You could split the file at the end of each group of SQL statements and then import one after the other.

Comment: It doesn't help, cause in 2 of the tables information is about few GBs and can't split it.

Comment: You could split an insert statement into one insert for one field and then update statements for each of the rest of the fields.

Comment: @SomeName Why can't you split it? I'm sure you are not inserting every row in one statement (not even sure that's possible). You can split into inserting 100 rows at a time. `insert into table (fields) values (row1 values), (row2 values), ..., (row100 values)`

Comment: I just can't open the file to see how is it inside.
I dump it with MySQL Administrator if there is any matter, cause I just have a MySQL user&psswd(no ssh and etc.)

Comment: The usual annoyance, inadequate hosting packages being spec'd. If a person's dealing with multi-gigabyte databases, they'll probably need ssh access. Then it's a case of uploading a compressed file, uncompressing and importing from the command line. No mess of dealing with php overhead, network transmission issues, etc. that cause the import to fail.

Comment: @SomeName: How in the world do you have a VPS without SSH access? And if so, what are you using PuTTy for?